# Have to input twice after validation (Java)

Tags: java, loops, validation

I am trying to validate the users input when prompted to enter a Name so that only Letters are accepted, however, when I do that it I have to enter a name twice until it prints the next line.

This is my code:

```
System.out.println("Enter First Name");
        queueArray[last].setfName(in.next().toUpperCase());  

        while(!in.next().matches("[a-zA-Z,]+")){
            System.out.println("Invalid Input");
            System.out.printLn("Enter First Name");
            queueArray[last].setfName(in.next().toUpperCase()); 
        }
```

I am not sure which part of the code is causing this issue.

Comment: Put `in.next()` into a variable first before checking if it matches anything. More importantly, learn to walk mentally (or on paper) through your code and visualize what it is doing as it runs. This is a *necessary* skill you need to improve if you're going to progress.

Comment: You call `next()` once in your `while` line, and again in your `setfName` line. Each call to `next` gets new input.

Comment: I recommend you read ["How to debug small programs"](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thank you for the advice, I will keep this in mind.

Answer (score -1):

Possible solution:

```
System.out.println("Enter First Name");
String input = in.next();
queueArray[last].setfName(input.toUpperCase());  

while(!input.matches("[a-zA-Z,]+")){
    System.out.println("Invalid Input");
    System.out.printLn("Enter First Name");
    queueArray[last].setfName(in.next().toUpperCase()); 
}
```